# Simulating zoomToRect with a plain uiview

Tags: ios, uiview

Just wondering if anyone knows a good way to simulate UIScrollView's zoomToRect method but with an UIView. Using a CGAffineTransform to scale is working well but I still can't figure out how to zoom to a specific rectangle. Any clues out there?

Comment: i have seen some questions like this on this site will searching for pdf reader example code and i came to a conclusion that it is really hard to achieve by any proper means.

Comment: Oh boy...had that fear myself. By any chance do you have a link to these articles? I've searched using all kinds of keywords but to no avail! :( I would greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: I was searching for displaying pdf on ios devices, thats when i found out about it.